# camera position in UNITY

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I am making a game(2D) in which an object runs with a velocity and jumps onto the coming platforms and I have made the camera as the child of the game object(i.e the main player) in the hierarchy. The problem is that whenever my game object get rotated on striking the platform or obstacle the main camera also starts getting rotated. I am unable to sort out this problem, Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can either lock rotation for the Camera in the Inspector or you create a Camerascript to follow you player manuell. Seconed is better because you can easily add smoothe, deadzones or camera effects like shake on dmg taken to the camera.

Example for the script from the unity page:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CompleteCameraController : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject player;       //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object


    private Vector3 offset;         //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
         //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
         offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
     void LateUpdate () 
    {
         // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
         transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }

}
```

Add this script to your MainCamera. Then drage your PlayerObject into the Field "player" in the camera Inspector.

If you need further help watch this video [here](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-ufo-tutorial/following-player-camera)

Comment: can you provide some resources for understanding the above 2 methods

Comment: @LoveBabbar this simply stores the distance between your object and the camera at the start and than in Update always sets the camera again to the position of the object but keeps the distance correctly.